# htaccess cannot match the whole URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am accessing the following URL:

```
http://example.com/welcome
```

Where I have the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?package=base&page=$1 [L]
```

I am expecting to return

```
package=base
page=welcome
```

But instead is giving me a "500 Internal Server Error".

If I change the htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^we(.*)$ /index.php?package=base&page=$1 [L]
```

It returns:

```
package=base
page=lcome
```

As expected, and if I change the htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)me$ /index.php?package=base&page=$1 [L]
```

It returns:

```
package=base
page=welco
```

As I was expecting as well.

Now the question is... why it does not math the whole URL? What I am missing here? How can I say "take everything the user passes and put it on a variable"?

Thanks!

Comment: _“What I am missing here?”_ – that the error log would have told you what the _actual_ reason of the error is … an endless internal redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite engine loops, so without some sort of conditions, the regex `^(.*)$` matches `index.php` and so on. Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?package=base&page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Lin for your fast, clear and accurate answer. I wish I could click the "up" button twice for you :-)